# What's the best practise to implement the action in the ios table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

For example, to implement the "Sign In" button as a table cell like image below, what's the best way? use uibutton to cover whole cell or use cell selector and label?

[image]

Comment: I think latter one is better, because in that case, you won't insert any other action-target logic yourself, which makes your code clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell selector and label version is better, but the *best* option is to option-drag a segue from the relevant cell(s) to the next view controller, or, if you want to fire an action instead, to option-drag from the cell to its own table view controller and select an `IBAction` method.